# Mail not delivered in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using Codeigniter 3 for my web app and I need to send e-mail with cerain data to all users. Each email contains slightly different data.

```
$this->load->model('Main_model');

$query = $this->Main_model->get_all_users();
$data = $query->result_array();

foreach ($data as $user) {
$this->email->from('My email', 'Me');
$this->email->to($user['username']);
$this->email->subject('Subject');
$this->email->message("Pretty long text with some variables in it." . $user['choice1'] . "End of message");
$this->email->send();}
```

The problem is that when I tested it, most users did not even get the email. Some of those who received mail complained that the part of the text ($user['choice']) was not in the text they received.

I have three questions:

1) Is there a better way to send emails, to ensure they are all delivered? Or am I forgetting something, maybe some server configuration? I don't know much about emails, so feel free to lecture me, I would be very glad.

2) Is there a better way to create text for the mail that to put it all between the parethesis in the message() function?

3) Should I even be sending emails in a foreach cycle? Is it possible that server broke down and that is the cause of most mails not being delivered? There is a maximum of 180 users that I have in database.

Comment: $this->email->message("Pretty long text with some variables in it.{$user['choice1'] }End of message");

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on why are some mails delivered and some are not? Does it have anything to do with mail server configuration?

Comment: what type of email ids? Are they correct? If you are using your own server to send emails then generally your daily/hourly email limit is 250. Check that how many mails are sent by you. If the mail is sent by you then not a problem, but if the email is bounce somehow then at least you got bounce email notification. Check your sender email id for that.

Comment: It did not even completely work with 20 emails. Could the issue with emails not being delivered have anything to do with the fact that I do not use SMTP, and that I use default Codeigniter settings? (I haven't changed anything but loaded the email library). Should I use SMTP? Will that solve my problem?